# How to configure custom CAS deployed through WSP package

Tags: code-access-security

I have been struggling with deployment of custom CAS. When I deploy my WSP package I get the following error:

> Security Exception  Description: The application attempted to perform
>   an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this
>   application the required permission please contact your system
>   administrator or change the application's trust level in the
>   configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the
>   permission of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.SharePointPermission,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Security, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' failed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.SharePointPermission,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Security, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' failed.]
>   System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Boolean ignoreCase) +0
>   System.Web.UI.Util.GetTypeFromAssemblies(ICollection assemblies,
>   String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase) +201
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean
>   ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError) +323
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String
>   baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly
>   assembly) +10864044
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary
>   parseData) +365

I figured out that I need a cutom CAS for my dlls but I have not found any article which would clearly state what exactly do.

I suppose that I should edit Package.Template.xml and add the custom policices there, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CodeAccessSecurity>
    <PolicyItem>
      <Assemblies>
        <Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyName$"
                  Version="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyVersion$"
                  PublicKeyBlob="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyPublicKeyBlob$"/>
      </Assemblies>
      <PermissionSet class="NamedPermissionSet" version="1" Name="SPRestricted">
        <IPermission class="AspNetHostingPermission" version="1" Level="Minimal" />
        <IPermission class="SecurityPermission" version="1" Flags="Execution" />
        <IPermission class="WebPartPermission" version="1" Connections="True" />
        <IPermission class="SharePointPermission" version="1" ObjectModel="True" />
        <IPermission class="SqlClientPermission" version="1" Unrestricted="true" />
        <IPermission class="Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.SharePointPermission, Microsoft.SharePoint.Security, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" version="1" ObjectModel="True" />
      </PermissionSet>
    </PolicyItem>
  </CodeAccessSecurity>
</Solution>
```

The code above was taken from this article:
http://alexanderst.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/adding-cas-permissions-to-wsp-in-sharepoint-2010/

I tried to use the code above but the exception is still the same. What assemblies should I state in the assembly section? Is it possible to use any preprocessor variables like in the example so I do not need to worry when the assemblies change? Has anyone stumbled on an article which would actually explain what the xml elements of CodeAccessSecurity mean/do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have figured that out myself - at least partly.

There are two task you have to do:

- pick the right permissions to give to your assemblies
- choose/state all assemblies that are involved (that should have the permissions) - this probably means that you need to state all the assemblies that violate the policy, hence those that need to be given the permissions

And my final xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CodeAccessSecurity>
    <PolicyItem>
      <Assemblies>
        <Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyName$"
                  Version="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyVersion$"
                  PublicKeyBlob="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyPublicKeyBlob$"/>
        <Assembly Name="Ninject"
                  Version="3.0.0.0"
                  PublicKeyBlob="0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100f3fc252fdcdfdba2e6d41c88aa5d644aa480c3776f4d7a3f02625347a53fef16b3940741285b67067480cc1eda51f1a9b255cc3af2dcf77325621bd9f644de9e1311a5d2f8bd3054573da970c33566033d91c0fe4420d5b01f996a32ae3a44fad49974edb8546f418eca586ea085a1a175a1b79d6ec84f75d4b814a40b2abcb9" />

        <!-- some other assemblies that I removed -->
      </Assemblies>
      <PermissionSet class="NamedPermissionSet" version="1" Name="TrackWebpartsPermissions">
        <IPermission class="AspNetHostingPermission" version="1" Level="Minimal" />
        <IPermission class="SecurityPermission" version="1" Flags="Execution" />
        <IPermission class="WebPartPermission" version="1" Connections="True" />
        <IPermission class="SharePointPermission" version="1" ObjectModel="True" />
        <IPermission class="SqlClientPermission" version="1" Unrestricted="true" />

        <IPermission class="ReflectionPermission" version="1" Flags="ReflectionEmit, RestrictedMemberAccess"/>
        <IPermission class="Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.SharePointPermission, Microsoft.SharePoint.Security, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" version="1" ObjectModel="True" />
      </PermissionSet>
    </PolicyItem>
  </CodeAccessSecurity>
</Solution>
```

However, I still don't understand what exactly you can and can't write into the IPermission elements.